# When and where do we write the "url.do" in struts1

Tags: java, struts-1

I have seen a couple of files in which we sometimes use the "url.jsp" but there are sometimes when we use "url.do" in the struts-config file in struts-1 .
Can anyone explain what do we actually mean by writing this ".do" in the URL.

Comment: There is no special reason, just to hide kind of page we are using (i.e jsp, html etc) and some times also to hide actual url

Comment: So how will the web-container come to know that it is calling the Action class or the jsp page in the struts-config file specification?

Comment: That was the URL mapping you will specify in web.xml (web descriptor) file to map your servlet to invoke when you hit urls matching your pattern

Comment: Is .do only used ti redirect to an Action class?

Comment: don't be confused with redirect. your action classes will be mapped to particular url patterns. If you register with .do url pattern for your `ActionServlet`, when ever you hit url with the extention .do, your `ActionServlet` will work as front end controller to map to particular action. same way if your action is already mapped to any of your action classes you can redirect to it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect the control to a different action, we need to use the e.g. `redirectAction.do`

There should be a corresponding action-mapping with path `/redirectAction` present which would then pass on the control to that action.

Also, this `.do` is default URL pattern for Struts 1. The same can be changed in "web.xml" file under the node `<servlet-mapping>`.
e.g. `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 0):

`.do` is the default Struts 1 URL mapping extension.

You use it when you need to reference an action, e.g., a redirect.